# ns1:FailedAuthenticationThe security token could not be authenticated or authorized

Tags: php, xml, soap

here is my xml code for authentication:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:esf="esf">
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">

        <wsse:UsernameToken  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

        <wsse:Username>my_username</wsse:Username>

        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">my_password</wsse:Password>

        </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
     </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <esf:createSessionRequest>
     <tin>my_bin</tin>
     <x509Certificate>my_cert</x509Certificate>
    </esf:createSessionRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

there is connection to site

```
   try{ $CreateSession = $SessionService>__doRequest 
   ($Create_session_xml, 'https://esf.gov.kz:8443/esfweb/ws/SessionService wsdl', '', SOAP_1_2);

   echo $CreateSession;// here I get error: FailedAuthenticationThe security token could not be authenticated or authorized

  } catch(SoapFault $e){
  echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
  }
```

I registered on this site, checked it. So problems with my datas no.

is there any idea? please help, I searched through internet, no results.

Edit: Initialization of the soap client taken from the comments.

```
$SessionService = new SoapClient(NULL, [ 
    "location" => "esf.gov.kz:8443/esf-web/ws/SessionService", 
    "uri" => "esf-test.kgd.gov.kz:9443", 
    "style" => SOAP_DOCUMENT, 
    "use" => SOAP_LITERAL, 
    "stream_context" => $context 
]);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us, how your SoapClient is initialized and which options you use for your SoapClient? If the `trace` option is enabled, you can see the last request and response of the client. Just use `$SessionService->__getLastRequest()` and `$SessionService->__getLastResponse()`. Perhaps the send and recieved xml data contain more informations about the occured error.

Comment: Thank you, Marcel!                                                                                  $SessionService = new SoapClient(NULL,  
    array(  
        "location" => "https://esf.gov.kz:8443/esf-web/ws/SessionService",  
        "uri"      => "https://esf-test.kgd.gov.kz:9443",  
        "style"    => SOAP_DOCUMENT,  
        "use"      => SOAP_LITERAL,
        "stream_context" => $context
    ));     I will try to use your advice. Thanks a lot for your response.